# magento 2 Show a confirmation pop up in check out page while submitting the form

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, popup

can you please help me how to Show a confirmation pop up in check out page while submitting the form in magento2.

Comment: What's the form which you try to submit?

Comment: Place order button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy file from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js

to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/payment/default.js

find **placeOrder: function (data, event)** and edit this function as given below

```
if(confirm("Are you sure to place order?") == true){
   //default function code
}else{
   return false;
}
```

**e.g.**

```
placeOrder: function (data, event) {

            if(confirm("Are you sure to place order?") == true){
                var self = this;

                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                if (this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                    this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

                    this.getPlaceOrderDeferredObject()
                        .fail(
                            function () {
                                self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                            }
                        ).done(
                            function () {
                                self.afterPlaceOrder();

                                if (self.redirectAfterPlaceOrder) {
                                    redirectOnSuccessAction.execute();
                                }
                            }
                        );

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Now run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: I have checked it, and it's working fine. Ask me if you encounter any problem.

Comment: thanks dinesh you have saved my time it's working http://prntscr.com/hg6wbe

Comment: I’m happy to help :)

Comment: On Place order button it works fine, How can we apply same on "continue to Paypal" (Under paypal method - before redirecting to paypal)?

Comment: @GunJanMehta You have to make changes paypal.js file which is located at vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal.js 

There you will find a function `payWithPayPal: function () {`

You have to add the logic in this function.

Comment: Which component should be included to use "confirm()" method in a different JS file?

Comment: @AhsanHorani "confirm" is a default function. You can use it in any js file.